# Is my theorem correct? $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for $x\geq a$ iff $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$ for $x\geq a$ and $f(a)=g(a)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to invent a theorem by inspection, which is $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for $x\geq a$ iff  $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$  for $x\geq a$ and $f(a)=g(a)$.

Is it correct?

Comment: No, this is not correct. One direction is true, and the other is not.

Comment: If you want to make an 'if and only if' statement, then you should change the $f(a) = g(a)$ part.

Comment: no, not at all. let $f(x)$ be a step function and $g(x)$ be a (weakly) smaller step function, they're not even differentiable.

Comment: He obviously implies the functions are differentiable for $x>a$, as he makes assumptions about the derivatives!

Comment: I just realized you also need to change the statement about the derivatives, as if $f^\prime$ is smaller than $g^\prime$ for some $x$'s, then it can also be greater afterwards without $f$ growing greater than $g$

Comment: @PascalEngeler: The assumption about derivatives holds in one direction only

Comment: @MPW: The "theorem statement" is not well written. For instance, $f(a) = g(a)$ apparently is a consequence of $f \le g$, which I am pretty sure isn't what OP intends.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant to say,

Suppose $f,g$ are differentiable functions such that $f(a) = g(a)$, then,

$$f(x) \le g(x) \quad \forall x \ge a \iff f'(x) \le g'(x) \quad \forall x \ge a$$

This is false.

You are essentially claiming that $f(x) - g(x)$ is decreasing, which leads to a counter example easily: Let $h(x) = -\sin^2 x$

Choose any $g(x)$ such that $g(0) = 0$ and let $f(x) = g(x) - \sin^2 x$

Comment: Could you prove in both directions?

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014: What do you mean by that? One way is true (inequality between derivatives implying the inequality between the functions), but it is an easy to show corollary of a well known theorem and almost anyone who has some calculus experience knows it like the back of their hand.

Comment: By assuming the right side is satisfied first and prove that the left is either correct or incorrect.

Comment: what is the  name of the well known corollary?

Comment: The theorem is the Mean-Value-Theorem. See this: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/meanvalue.html. The corollary is probably too trivial a consequence to merit a name. (I haven't heard of one). Of course, trying to prove it independent of the MVT might be interesting (the page I link has some discussion in that direction).

Answer (score 0):

let $ h(x) = f(x)-g(x) $ then $ h(x) $ is decreasing fuction  for $ x \leq 0 $  since $ h'(x) \leq 0  $

so $h(x) \leq 0 $ for $ x \leq 0 $ since $h(a)=0$

Comment: Umm.. what's the ploblem in my answer?

Comment: This proves only one direction of the OP's if and only if statement. The other direction is false.